# Programmatically Stop and RESUME AWS EC2 based on activity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My org wants to minimize the cost of EC2 instances and I'm thinking about how I can pause it and resume it programmatically.

I have found posts on stackoverflow where you can set up a lambda function to pause an EC2 instance when it's idling for a long time. My question is, how can I resume it automatically when there're requests to the website.

More info:
My EC2 is used to deployed web applications. They are NOT static websites. Right now mostly are t2.small, but one is t2.xlarge for a ckan open data portal. They are not very busy at all. There is one for DocuemntDB access.

Comment: What website? Starting instances take time. Whatever you do there will be large delay before an instance can be used.

Comment: Do you just run a single instance? What is the size of the instance? What are you running on the instance (is it just a static site, or does it do something complex)? Does the instance become fully busy at other times of the day? Please Edit your question to provide full details of your current setup, and to answer these questions.

Comment: What is deployed onto the EC2 instance? What functionality does it do? If you can provide more info in terms of OS/application/usage there might be multiple solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can **Stop** an Amazon EC2 instance.

When Stopping an instance, you can either choose to **Shutdown** the instance, or **Hibernate** the instance.

**Shutdown** is just like choosing the option on a normal computer -- the operating system does a graceful shutdown and the computer is turned off. When it is next turned on, it goes through the complete boot process.

**Hibernate** saves the memory to disk so that, when it is again Started, everything is in place exactly as it was before the hibernation. It can take a while to read the memory from disk.

You would need to do some experimentation to determine how quickly the instance is available again after Starting from hibernation.

See: [Hibernate your On-Demand or Reserved Linux instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html)

In both cases, the instance is Stopped and there is no charge for the EC2 instance (but charges will continue for the Amazon EBS disk storage being used.)

There is **no method provided to "automatically resume" the instance**. Any traffic sent to the instance will fail, since the computer is turned off. You would need to trigger some external mechanism that would Start the instance, such as calling an AWS Lambda function or running a AWS CLI command on your own computer.

If your goal is to minimize costs, start by choosing the correctly-sized instance. As traffic increases during the day, you could either stop/resize/start the instance to a bigger size (but this has outage time), or **run multiple instances behind a load balancer** and change the number of instances (but the Load Balancer incurs additional costs).